# itemTemplate item id not existing in code behind

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I am trying to create textboxes that are equal to the number of rows in grid view (databound from db). here is my markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="quizGrid" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="admissionNO" HeaderText="Admission NO"/>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="studentName" HeaderText="Name" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="marks" > </asp:Textbox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

but when i use the marks in code behind it says

> quizGrid_marks_0 does not exists in the current context

what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Your question is not clear. First of all you can't access your textbox like that in your code behind file, next you said "I am trying to create textboxes" but in question you are trying to fetch the id. Please be specific.

Comment: @RahulSingh trying to create mean, iwant  textboxes as much as the rows are generated, secondly i just type marks="" and it says mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your textbox like that in code behind file, rather you need to find them in `RowDataBound` event like this:-

```
protected void quizGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TextBox marks = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("marks");
                txtMarks.Text = "Test";
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**

Okay, suppose you have a button `btnGetData` with button click event as `btnGetData_Click`, then you can find the textbox text by looping through the gridview rows like this:-

```
protected void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView quizGrid = (GridView)Page.FindControl("quizGrid");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in quizGrid.Rows) 
    {
        TextBox marks = (TextBox)row.FindControl("marks");
    }
}
```

Comment: its an event right? i want to get the text of all textboxes on click of a button

Comment: Okay and where is that button located? Outside the gridview or inside?